# Pasar de un fragment a otro

Tags: android, recyclerview

Tengo un fragment y dentro de el fr[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]agment tengo un recyclerview con un cardview el cual tiene un botón, y están ubicados en el fragment 1 y deseo que con el botón pase al fragment 2, lo declaro en el onBindViewHolder y saco el evento del click listener, pero no encuentro como hacer que pase al otro fragment. alguna ayuda por favor llevo mas de dos semanas con este problema.

Comment: Hola user. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Pon el codigo en formato de texto, no como imagen. Para formatearlo pulsa `ctrl+k` o el boton `{}`. Mira [ask] para más informacion. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

En el código que tienes comentado, cambia el `.show()` por

```
transaction.replace(R.id.id_del_fragment_del_layout, nuevoFragment);
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
```

Como puedes ver la [documentacion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#show(android.app.Fragment)) , el método `.show()` sirve para mostrar un `Fragment`, que haya sido oculto mediante el método `.hide()` de `FragmentTransaction`, en tu caso, lo que necesitas es reemplazar el `Fragment`, por el nuevo `Fragment` de `Tab_Mapas_Fragment()`, la transición te he puesto esa, pero aparte de ser opcional, tienes en el enlace de mas arriba, las distintas opciones.

La opción de `.replace()`, te servirá si no necesitas mantener el estado del Fragment anterior, en caso de que necesitases mantener el `Fragment` anterior, deberías utilizar los métodos `.remove()` y `.add()`. De esa manera cuando cambies de `Fragment`, y le des al botón de atras, te volverá al `Fragment` anterior en el último estado que lo dejaste.

```
((AppCompactActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
    .remove(referencia_al_fragment_a_reemplazar)
    .commit();
((AppCompactActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    .replace(R.id.contenedor_del_fragment, nuevoFragmento)
    .commit();
```

Comment: Hola Ictus, puedes explicar más tu respuesta? Mira [answer] para más informacion. Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias. sobre pone el fragment al existente, e intente el codigo abajo y no hace nada. muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Prueba a ver si así te vale, llevo un tiempo sin tocar android y no tengo medios ahora para probarlo ahora mismo...

Answer (score 0):

```
Fragment fragmenthijo = new fragmentnuevo();
FragmentTransaction transaction = ((menuActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container_fragments, fragmenthijo ).commit();
```

Necesitas hacerlo con replace, lo que va a hacer es remplazar el fragment actual por otro nuevo. Pero para esto necesitamos FrameLayout en la activity donde contiene los fragments, cada vez que remplazamos el fragment le decimos que lo remplace en el FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container_fragments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Perdón si no me hago entender bien, hace dias no toco Android. [Aquí](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) encontraras más información de lo que hablo.